# Trying to implement sharekit getting errors

Tags: iphone, ios7, sharekit

Hello I am new to iphone development. I'm trying to implement share kit and am getting this error

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>     "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SSReadingList", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in libShareKit.a(SHKReadingList.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

dont know what to do i tried using https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit this link and all the steps are done still what is this error about have no clue about

Comment: Just got the answer i was missing safariservices.framework